# Opening multiple windows (each with different tabs) when Chrome starts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I need Chrome to startup with multiple windows with different tabs in each.
Is there an extension I can use for this or a setting I don't know about? I am able to do this in Firefox using session manager but I cannot use Firefox for this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running Windows, follow these steps:

1. Install a second Chrome: [How to have two separate installations of Chrome on one PC](https://superuser.com/questions/1013687/is-it-possible-to-have-two-separate-installations-of-chrome-on-one-computer/1013781)
2. Open your favorite text editor (if you don't have one, use Notepad)
3. Write the following batch code:

   ```
   @echo off
   cd "path/to/chrome"
   start chrome.exe

   cd "path/to/chrome2"
   start chrome.exe
   exit
   ```
4. Save as chrome_launcher.bat
5. Replace Chrome shortcut with a shortcut to the batch file
6. Disable sync on both Chrome applications if necessary
7. Change on startup section of settings in both Chrome applications differently

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Unpin Chrome from your taskbar. Make sure you unpin all instances.  Then go into your menu button and find Chrome again.  Open a window and pin that window to the taskbar.  Solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Is that on a Windows environment? It would be nice if you explained your needs better ... anyway:

You can set which pages will be loaded when Chrome starts in `Settings` >> `On Startup` >> `Open a specific page or set of pages`. Set the pages you want to be loaded.

Also, if you need them to be loaded on Windows Startup, then you can copy a Chrome shortcut to the Startup Folder. On Windows 8, it is located at:
`%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

I hope it helps.

Comment: I know how to make Chrome start when windows starts. I am trying to find out how to make two windows of chrome launch when I launch chrome itself.

Comment: Allright. Have you tried changing the ON STARTUP section of settings in Chrome, as I told you in the answer? It should work; if it doesn't, please tell us your Chorme version.

Comment: yes I have done this but that still only opens one window of chrome with one set of tabs which is not what I need. I want to open two windows of chrome with different tabs.

Comment: There is a "Session Buddy" extension in the Chrome Web Store but it is not automatic, would require 2 more clicks.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't understood your question then. Sorry for wasting your time... I have no clue of how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I use AutoHotkey to open up five windows of Chrome across three monitors, with one on the leftmost (primary) monitor, and two on each of the other two monitors. My script is below. It's not the most elegant; I use 600ms breaks between actions to avoid issues since the computer is still slow when starting up.

```
#s::
;Open Chrome
Run https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
Sleep, 600
;Maximize the window
WinMaximize
Sleep, 600
;Open new window
Run Chrome
Sleep, 600
;Send to middle monitor
send, {LWin Down}{Shift Down}{Right}{Shift Up}{LWin up}
Sleep, 600
;move to left half of middle monitor
send, {LWin Down}{Left}{LWin up}
Sleep, 600
;open new window
Run Chrome
Sleep, 600
;Send to right half of middle monitor
send, {LWin Down}{Right}{LWin up}
Sleep, 600
;open new window
Run Chrome
Sleep, 600
;Send window to right monitor
send, {LWin Down}{Right}{LWin up}
Sleep, 600
send, {LWin Down}{Right}{LWin up}
Sleep, 600
;Open new window
Run Chrome
Sleep, 600
;Send window to right half of right monitor
send, {LWin Down}{Right}{LWin up}
Sleep, 600
return
```

Answer (score 0):

This extension works quite well:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-session-manager/iaiomicjabeggjcfkbimgmglanimpnae