# Is it possible to have two separate installations of Chrome on one computer?

Tags: google-chrome

I recently have a job that wants me to do a fresh install of Chrome, but I don't want to lose all of my extensions and settings.

So is it possible to install Chrome again so I have two separate installations working under the same email?

Keep in mind I don't want dev versions, portable versions, or previous versions. Both need to be the same stable updatable version of Chrome.

Comment: Yes. Install a portable version for the second one.

Comment: Can't do that. I need the non-portable versions.

Comment: <shrug> Then use a VM.

Comment: Would a second profile be enough for you?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Assuming you don't want to run a virtual machine to have a second instance, you can have two different chrome instances if you use a os sandboxing software. For example Sandboxie.

Here is an image of me running two chromes. I didn't demo logging out of one but you can easily do that.
[image: Running two Chrome.exe processes using sandboxie]

And here is an image showing Chrome running as two processes.
[image]

Comment: That's the way to go

Comment: 2019 EDIT: You can also use Windows 10's Sandbox feature if you have a pro license and have enabled the feature

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. The only option to do so is to use the unofficial [portable chrome](http://www.chrome-portable.com/), or to use multiple systems (physical or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

> two separate installations working under the same email?

That may be problematic, if you wish to login to Chrome on both. 
Definitely not possible on one Chrome installation with two profiles.

> a job that wants me to do a fresh install of Chrome, but I don't want to lose all of my extensions and settings.

So in that 'fresh install' , don't login to Chrome , only login to Google. 
Then there's no way for it to mess up with what you have in https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync .
Copying indidivual bookmarks/bookmark folders is easy by drag&dropping between 
two Chrome windows from different profiles/installations.

Given that you don't want Canary or portable versions, and probably not any 
other Chromium based browsers either, how about just downloading a Chromium version with the same build-number as the latest stable release of Chrome ?

You can choose to either just download, unpack and run it , 
or download and install it.  One thing is that it won't automatically update.

Is this for a work or home computer ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is possible**

**How to do it:** Install two different versions of chrome. *For example, you can use the regular version + the developer version.*

**How to find/download different chrome versions:** Currently you can find other versions of chrome near the bottom of the chrome download page (https://www.google.com/chrome/).

[image: Different versions of chrome]

**Download links** (5-2023):

- [Regular](https://www.google.com/chrome/)
- [Chrome Dev](https://www.google.com/chrome/dev/)
- [Chrome Enterprise](https://chromeenterprise.google/browser/download/)
- [Chrome Beta](https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/)
- [Chrome Canary (nightly)](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/)
- [ungoogled-chromium (github repo)](https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium)

**My setup: (confirmed working)** I personally use [ungoogled chromium](https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium) + the [developer version](https://www.google.com/chrome/dev/) and they are completely separate for me.
For example, I can block one with windows firewall rules and the other one will keep working. Which is not something possible using different profiles.

Comment: This tells how to FIND other Chrome versions, bit does not answer the question of whether it is possible to have two different versions on the same computer at the same time.

Comment: I thought I answered this in the 2nd paragraph. It is possible and it is running on my PC using two different versions. I can run both at the same time. My use case is sending one through a proxy while allowing the other one to go through my regular internet connection. I can modify my answer if thats not clear. Or let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: It is not clear. Further, while the title does say "is it possible", read any such simplistic question to actually be asking "how do I". Simply asking if something is possible is technically off topic here, because we want substantive questions. I recommend rewriting your answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, nonintrusive way is to install Chrome and a clone/branch of Chrome such as Brave.  All the Chrome add-ons work and the menu options etc are identical.

This is what I have done.  I use one for development with all tools enabled and appropriate add-ons.  And the other for browsing.